# What's the difference between pop-in and pop-up?

Tags: user-experience

Can someone point out what pop-in stand for? Our friend Google is not helpful in this direction :)

Although, what I've found is the following: "Pop In = The window moves across the current window on top", but isn't it what a pop-up does?

Thanks in advance! Cheers!

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. What does this have to do with javascript?

Comment: *"isn't it what a pop-up does?"* - A "pop up" doesn't necessarily move, it often just appears in place, but in my opinion the terms "pop up" and "pop in" are talking about virtually the same thing.

Comment: In what context? I've never head of a pop-in in JS. If you're talking about a certain library, could you name it.

Comment: `Pop-in` should be animation for element to appear, while `Pop-out` should be for element disappearing.

Comment: If "Pop In = The window moves across the current window on top", then I would assume the distinction is in the animation effect.  Pop in slides in, while pop up usually appears relatively close to where its final presentation location will be (using a fade in or scaling).  This is all just opinion, however.  This is more a question on UX or design practices.

Answer (score 0):

Pop-ins are pop ups that automatically open on the user's screen, pushed by an algorithm that analyses your browsing data/cookies and decides what is the right moment to display it. 
E.g. pop in that asks you to subscribe to a newsletter after few seconds you land on a website/e-commerce.
Companies that sell these kind of services are Netmining (netmining.com) and Ignition One (https://www.ignitionone.com/).
In general I hate these kind of pop ups: they are really intrusive and interrupt the user' experience and navigation. They only work if they are really relevant for the user and contextual to his/her current navigation path.